# Camel : How to invoke direct route from within a Method in another route to get the response of the direct route

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I have the below scenario :

```
 from("servlet:/?matchOnUriPrefix=true")
                    .to("cxfbean:jaxrsServices?providers=jaxrsProviders")
// returns a string of consolidated requests
                    .to("direct:invokeHCASService");



            from("direct:invokeHCASService")

                    /*Split the requests string using the XML token*/ /* sets header("CamelSplitSize") as split size*/
                    .split().tokenizeXML("<soapenv:Envelope")                           // ("<SOAP-ENV:Body>")//.streaming()
                    /*For Processing Requests in Parallel*/ 
                    .parallelAggregate()                                                // .parallelProcessing()

                    /*To Invoke SOAP Services registered in GRM (Eg. CSI)*/
                    .to("bean:dme2ServiceUtil?method=frameRequest") // frame request
                    .to("bean:invokeService?method=invoke") // invoke request
                    .to("bean:dme2ServiceUtil?method=getResponse") // get response

                    /*Implementing ArrayList Aggregation Strategy to gather all Responses processed in parallel */
                    .aggregate(constant(true), batchAggregationStrategy())
                    /* Aggregation completion strategy [To stop aggregation] set to No. of requests split */
                    .completionSize(header("CamelSplitSize"))                           // .completionTimeout(BATCH_TIME_OUT)


                    .bean(new Consolidate(), "getConsolidatedResults");
```

Here from my route1 which returns a string ----- my rest service response is rendered from the route1 and another flow goes to route2.

I want pass this string input to route2 and get the response in route1 to pass to the calling client.

I can also perform the things in route2 within the bean in route1 itself but here I need to use parallel aggregate and aggreagate the results so I need to use routs in this case. Any help is much appreciated.

Note : Is using CamelProxy a solution ?? (if so please provide a sample)

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you need a little more? as I can see now 1. you get request 2. call jaxrs web service 3. pass result to the route2 4. process it in parallel 5. aggregate results 6. send it back to client. So, what is wrong with that? Sorry I did not get a point...

Comment: The cxfbean routes to a bean interface and implementation so 1) the bean's response is sent back to the client 2) another flow goes with this response being passed to the proceeding routes

Comment: What i exactly want is the response from the consolidate bean at the end of routes to be sent to the client

Comment: is it not doing now? I mean client->request->route1->route2->response-route1->client must be there right now. I do not understand why you said that response from first `.to("cxfbean:` sends back to client. There is no fork in your code. it can happens only if route2 did not change body. Also for parallel processing you need specify `parallelProcessing` not necessary  `parallelAggregate`

Comment: Correct - route2's response is not rendered back to route1. This cxfbean is routed to a class (interface n implementation) where i write my logic for processing and geneating a string which has to be split.

Comment: "route2's response is not rendered back to route1" - that is a problem. Only one thing I can recommend - debug your code and find at what point response is missing. Just for test try to put some simple response in the body at last point of route2 (`Consolidate,getConsolidatedResults`) and see will it appear at the end of route1.